# Syntax highliting for Angular2+ questions

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

When looking at [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/169519/web-developer-profile-page-in-angular-2), I noticed that the syntax highlighting wasn't that great, most likely due to the mix of one block with HTML and Angular2 and blocks with TypeScript.

I decided to improve it by adding the necessary language hints -- `<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->` -- but looking through [the canonical answer on the main Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109), I cannot find either TypeScript or Angular2+ .

Is there support for these two languages and is it simply not documented? Or are these missing?

Comment: There might be support for these languages in google prettify. If that's the case, lang-or-tag-here should be the prettify declaration for angular. Worst case you should consider highlighting for JS

Answer (score 3):

You used the wrong name for the language hints. I change the question in [revision 5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/169519/5) to fix these.

The [GitHub repo for Googles code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), isn't incredibly descriptive on how to specify the languages, however it's common for them to follow the format of `lang-*`.

In this case, using `lang-html` for the HTML code worked fine. And using `<!-- language-all: lang-typescript -->` worked to make the rest of the codeblocks format with the TypeScript syntax highlighting.

---

I also removed the JavaScript tag, as TypeScript is a super set of JavaScript, and is a different language. This IMO should have defaulted to using `language-all: lang-typescript`, but didn't.

Since the OP also isn't using SASS in the question I removed that tag. I also removed the Angular.JS tag too, as it's using Angular-2+. Which now defaults the codeblocks to use TypeScript as the default syntax highlighting.

Comment: To note, TypeScript's language isn't set [on the tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/typescript/info). So I'm not really sure why it works...